# How to install new module/package in python coding online environment?

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

I want to install third party package in python online coding environments. Could you please tell me how we can achieve this?

The below line needs to execute
**from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTestV1 as STT**
when I run the above line, I am getting the following error,

**Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "..\Playground\", line 1, in  
    \ufefffrom watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTestV1 as STT 
ImportError: No module named 'watson_developer_cloud'

Even tried the below command in CODE Playground but it throwing incorrect syntax.
**pip install watson_developer_cloud**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to execute `pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud` 
and not `pip install watson_developer_cloud`

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Comment: Hi FedorTP,  I ran the same command in SOLO Learn Code PlayGround Environment and i see this message: File "..\Playground\", line 1 
    pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud 
              ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax \

Comment: wait, i will try everything on my server :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install packages when using SoloLearn. You need to ask SoloLearn's administrators to install the package for you.

The python playground includes some of the most popular packages but it's very limited in terms of what you can do if the package you want to use is not there.